# I don't have a scanner. How can I clean up a photo of a piece of paper?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photos, scanner

Recently I've been asked to print a piece of paper, sign it, scan it and then send it back via email.

Unfortunately I don't own a scanner.

I'm hoping I can take a photo of the paper and then manipulate it in Photoshop so that it looks similar to the output of a scanner.

So far, I've taken the image, used the Perspective Crop Tool to straighten it and then rotated it - but now I need to try and get the text crisp and clear and the colour of the paper as white as possible. At the moment it has a slight blueish tinge from the top left hand corner.

Can anyone advise on what I need to do? I tried creating an adjustment layer with levels - but since I didn't really know what I was doing it ended up making the output look even worse.

Comment: How about the alternate route of just signing the PDF, if that's what it was originally? You can generate a valid signature with a piece of paper & a web cam.

Comment: I would be amazed if you can achieve what you are after. I would consider an alternative, or, pop out to a local printers and use their scanners

Comment: @Tetsujin That's a great idea, I didn't even know you could do that!

Comment: see http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/signing-pdfs.html Shall I make this an answer, as it's way less trouble then playing in photoshop?

Comment: @Tetsujin I thnk that technically the right answer would be how to go about doing it in Photoshop - because even though your answer worked perfectly (thanks!), someone in the future who wants to actually use Photoshop to tidy up a photo of a piece of paper (which, say, didn't come as a signable PDF) won't find your solution useful.

Comment: Fair enough - right now it's looking like an XY Problem to me, but I get your point.

Comment: If the purpose of scanning is to evidence a signature, you are going overboard.  Banks will deposit a check based on a cellphone image.  A 4 MP camera with the image of the page filling the screen will be equivalent to fax resolution, and fax is normally accepted for this purpose.  Since fax is B&W, you are probably wasting your time with color correction.  You can improve the contrast (make what is supposed to be black darker, paper background white).  Then convert to greyscale, or start with a higher resolution and convert to B&W, like a fax.  You aren't displaying this in a gallery.

Comment: You should use software intended for document processing not software for photo processing. Photoshop is for the latter, Adobe Acrobat (just as an example) for the former. Acrobat offers a number of Document Processing Tools to "get the text crisp and clear and the colour of the paper as white as possible" - very easy to use. If you don't have Acrobat you can use the free software IrfanView (see explanation for your purpose at https://irfanview-forum.de/archive/index.php/t-7482.html)

Comment: If you use a smartphone for your "scanning" you don't need the step with Photoshop (or Acrobat) at all. Just use an scanning app that does what you try to do with Photoshop. On Android I use the free Mobile Doc Scanner Lite or Scanbot for example.

Comment: Your aim should be to take the best possible picture of the document and thus avoid/minimize image enhancements. It's as simple as: crap in, crap out. No need for perspective correction, if you consciously try to avoid distortion while taking a picture - or take several pictures until you manage "by accident" one without. Or improvise a simple repro stand. I took a transparent plastic box and cut a hole in the bottom. For "scans" I place a document on the table, put the box over it (upside down), place the tablet over the hole and take the picture – no distortion at all.

Comment: Next is proper lightning. This will avoid/minimize the need for whitening the paper background. Experiment with different lighting sources, e.g. outside in direct sunlight, inside on the windowsill, or use an additional desk lamp (experiment with the angle of lighting the doument). Try different light colors, e.g. cool white vs. warm white led or fluorescent bulbs). Or adapt the white color balance of your camera/smartphone. Be carefull not to shade the document with your body. Strong lightning without reflections will give you crisp text - no need for post-processing.